# CFReadStream For HttpRequest

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-foundation

i have to develop a Terminal Tool app for create a Deamon to run every 20 second.

This Deamon simply do this step

- verify if exist a file: read inside this file a pass
- Read all serial_numbers from devices USB Connected
- Create an HTTP request and send on querystring this parameters

first 2 steph run perfectly but after send the HTTPRequest the main Thread exit from app because don't wait response.

this is my code for the HTTPRequest: (I have to use CoreFoundation Framework because the NSConnection from Foundation Framework not run)

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_arrayOfSerial count]; i++) {

        CFStringRef urlFirst = CFSTR("http://192.168.30.9:88/virtualBadge.aspx?token=");
        CFStringRef token =(CFStringRef)_codicePWD;
        CFStringRef urlSecond = CFSTR("&serial=");
        CFStringRef serial = (CFStringRef) [_arrayOfSerial objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"URL: %@%@%@%@", urlFirst,token,urlSecond,serial);

        CFStringRef strs[4];

        strs[0] = urlFirst;
        strs[1] = token;
        strs[2] = urlSecond;
        strs[3] = serial;

        CFArrayRef urlArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void*)strs, 4, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

        CFStringRef urlCompleta = CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, urlArray, CFSTR(""));
        NSLog(@"Url: %@",urlCompleta);

        CFURLRef myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, urlCompleta, NULL);

        CFStringRef headerFieldName = CFSTR("host");
        CFStringRef headerFieldValue = CFSTR("192.168.30.9");

        CFStringRef requestMethod = CFSTR("GET");
        CFHTTPMessageRef myRequest =CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, myURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
        CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(myRequest, headerFieldName, headerFieldValue);

        CFDataRef mySerializedRequest = CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(myRequest);
        if(CFHTTPMessageIsRequest(myRequest)){
            NSLog(@"Is a Request: OK");
            if(CFHTTPMessageIsHeaderComplete(myRequest)){
                NSLog(@"Header OK");
            }
        }

        CFReadStreamRef myReadStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, myRequest);
        CFOptionFlags events = kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered | kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes | kCFStreamEventNone | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted;

        CFStreamClientContext dataStreamContext = {
            0,
            self,
            (void *(*)(void *info))CFRetain,
            (void (*)(void *info))CFRelease,
            (CFStringRef (*)(void *info))CFCopyDescription
        };

        if(CFReadStreamSetClient(myReadStream, events, EvenCallBack, &dataStreamContext)){
            CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(myReadStream, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
        }
        if(CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream)){
            NSLog(@"Stream Open - ");
        }

        NSString *messReq = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData*)mySerializedRequest encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

        CFRelease(myRequest);
        CFRelease(myURL);
        CFRelease(urlArray);
        CFRelease(urlCompleta);
        CFRelease(myReadStream);

        NSLog(@"Serialized Request: %@", messReq);
//            NSLog(@"Request Send");
    }
```

"EvenCallBack" function never call because the main thread exit:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    Demone* demone = [[Demone alloc] init]; //This is the class that start all process
    [demone startDemone]; //Function start process
    [demone release];


}
NSLog(@"Exit");
return 0;
}
```

Where is my error?

why the app never wait response?

Comment: You start the demon, which probably goes into background. And before it can finish you release it. Than it is gone... so your app does what you told it to do. How does startDemone look like?

Comment: In start Demone i run all tre point... and the point run correctly... The http request work... but not work CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop... if i remove the [demone release]; from the Main nothing change.

Comment: From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop I would imply that you need to set a client and then wait for responses from the stream. Your app just quits after starting the demon.

Comment: this is true but... How i can wait the response from client? if i use a while the "EvenCallBack" never call... why?

Comment: the while blocks your main run loop and nothing else has time for computations. You may need to read up on runloops and such. you could consider running the request on a extra thread or such...

Comment: I have try to run the request on another thread... In this case when the request was send on another thread the main thread run to the end and exit... without whait the execution on secondary thread...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75729/discussion-between-eloreden-and-volker).

Comment: yes, you still have to wait on the main thread but give time to the other thread.

Comment: Yes ok... but how i can wait without while?

Comment: while loop is fine as long as you give the runloop computing time with for example `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3]];`

Comment: OK tnx like this the main thread keep alive and callback run!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the demon, which probably goes into background. And before it can finish you release it. Than it is gone...

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop) I would imply that you need to set a client and then wait for responses from the stream. Your app just quits after starting the demon.

You can use a while loop in your main and check if the stream is finished. Then you can exit. As long as you give the runloop computing time with for example `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3]];` in the while loop.

Comment: Tnx for all your Help!!